# Angular Universal: ng build does not build server files

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ng-build

I recently added SSR to my Angular app with Angular Universal (with express as the server) and I'm having trouble updaing my build and deploy steps. I was using a dockerfile in which I was having a build step: `ng build -c <environtmentName>` followed by a startup command `CMD ["node", "./dist/MyApp/main.js"]`.

After adding SSR the new structure came with a couple of new commands in package.json, including one for "build": `"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run MyApp:server:production"`.

I am now trying to add a "pure" build script that would build both the frontend app plus the server related content, like server.ts.
I have noticed that if I run the `ng build` command only the angular app is being built.
If I however run the `build:ssr` command though it builds the app in the first part (`ng build --prod`) and then it compiles and runs the server in the second `ng run MyApp:server:production`

I was not able to find a command that builds the server separately so that I can include it in my dockerfile. I do not want to run `ng run MyApp:server:production` in my dockerfile, I simply want to run it as the `CMD ["node", "./dist/MyApp/server/main.js"]` command for various reasons. The only workaround was to run the `build:ssr` - or equivalent commands related to different environments I'm targeting - locally, then build the docker image, ng build simply ignores the express server related files it seems.

Comment: Normally you need to build your server separately

Comment: @AndyNope the operation takes place during `ng run MyApp:server:production`. Is there any way I can isolate that part or is it just "magical" and I have to write my own script manually?

Comment: To be honest; I never deployed the server part myself and let GitLab do that automatically for me, but I can check the config at my projects... just a moment

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/universal Like I thought, you have to do a normal Build ng build --prod and then start the SSR separately... But I don't want to confuse the you because I've never done it manually. I am also following this now as I am interested in the correct solution.

Comment: @AndyNope yes, that's what the guide says and the server build is part of running the SSR, however for my docker setup I need to be running the server build separately from the step where I start the server. Thanks though

Comment: `npm run build:ssr`

Comment: @Pieterjan that builds AND starts the server. I need it to just build, either server + frontend or just the "server" express part

Comment: `npm run start:ssr` starts the server. `npm run build:ssr` only generates the browser+server bundles

Comment: @Pieterjan when adding angular universal only `build:ssr` was added as as npm task, and the contents are these: `"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run MyApp:server:production",`, there is no `start:ssr` for me. And `ng build` only does the client stuff, as mentioned, the server code is not compiled. Can you show me what you meant by `build:ssr` doing only the (full) build? Or could you show me how it looks in one of your projects?

Comment: [package.json](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/package.json#L17)